# Dynamic Style Property Values Based on Component Dimensions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I've got this React Native component:

```js
export default function BasicView(props: BasicViewProps): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        maxHeight: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        aspectRatio: 2,
        borderWidth: 10,
        borderColor: "black",
        backgroundColor: "red",
      }}
    >
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is working great for me. But when this view is smaller, the `borderWidth` looks too big. I'm wondering if there's a dynamic way to assign the value of the `borderWidth` with respect to the width *without* having to expose the `borderWidth` as a parameter in the `BasicViewProps`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for that, here is a good article:

https://blog.expo.dev/media-queries-with-react-native-for-ios-android-and-web-e0b73ed5777b

code sample from this page

```
import '@expo/match-media'
// Unleash the demo :D
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
export default function App() {
  const isTabletOrMobileDevice = useMediaQuery({    
    maxDeviceWidth: 1224,
    // alternatively...
    query: "(max-device-width: 1224px)"  
  });
  if (isTabletOrMobileDevice) {
    return (<Text>Hi Mobile Users </Text>)
  }
  return (<Text> Hello Desktop People</Text>)
}
```

so basically you could use isTabletOrMobileDevice there to set a different border.

You could alternatively use `Dimensions.addEventListener()` but I'm sure the first method should suit you. https://medium.com/@wcandillon/responsive-uis-in-react-native-a406b5d6c36a

Comment: Interesting. I'll take a look at these. I'm very new to React Native (and JS/TS) so at first glance I'm not connecting the dots on how to integrate these into my component, but I'll be reading these and doing some research. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer, I didn't get it was a react native question, thought it was just react because you tagged the question "reactjs"... basically the answer is the same, use media queries

Comment: Thanks for updating, and I've been looking into it and I'm not sure media queries is what I want. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like media queries are used (mostly) to determine the size/orientation of the device/browser screen? I can see that being helpful in certain scenarios, but I'm hoping to have the `borderRadius` scale off of the parent component, more likely. I'm hoping to have the component's `borderRadius`  display differently on the same device; so when the _button_ is smaller, I want a smaller `borderRadius` and when it's larger I want a larger `borderRadius`.

Comment: media queries are used to apply different styles depending on the size and orientation of a device indeed. I don't think you can get the borderRadius scale of your parent component unless you pass directly to the children a value to tell it what size it is. usually people pass an argument "variant". This variant argument could be calculated with media queries

Comment: Cool. Yeah, the more I research, the more it's looking like I'll need to expose some sort of argument for the component.